# Verification of proof for infinite series

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Prove that if $\sum {|{a_n}|} $ converges and $b_n$ is a bounded sequence, then $\sum{a_nb_n}$ converges.

Since ${b_n}$ is bounded $ \Rightarrow $ $\exists M > 0$, $\ni |{b_n}| \le M,\forall n  $

Therefore $|{a_nb_n}| \le |{a_n}||{b_n}| \le |{a_n}|M, \forall n$

$\sum|{a_n}|$ converges $\Rightarrow \sum{M|a_n|}$

By Comparison test, $\sum{|a_nb_n|}$ converges $\Rightarrow \sum{a_nb_n} $ converges (Theorem 33.5)

Can anyone check if my proof is sound?

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but what is Theorem 33.5?

Comment: $\sum|{a_n}|$ converges $\Rightarrow \sum{a_n}$ converges

Comment: I'd never known that was Theorem 33.5! Thanks!

Comment: haha I feel like that was sarcasm

Comment: It may help to indicate which textbook you are reading.

Comment: Analysis with an Introduction to Proof by Steven R. Lay Fifth Edition

Comment: Good old theorem 33.5. Almost as good as theorem A43.5.2

Comment: Your 4th line is missing something; If $\sum |a_n|$ converges then  (something  concerning $\sum M|a_n|$).